# pointers between vector<unique_ptr<myclass> > elements

Tags: c++, c++11, binary-tree, stdvector, unique-ptr

I have this class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class person
{
public:
    person(string name, string surname):_name(name), _surname(surname){}
    virtual ~person(){}
    void print()
    { cout  << _name << ' ' << _surname << endl
        << "mother: " << _mother->get_name() << ' ' << _mother->get_surname() << endl
        << "father: " << _father->get_name() << ' ' << _father->get_surname() << endl; 
    }
    string get_name(){return _name;}
    string get_surname(){return _surname;}

    void set_parents(person &mother, person &father)
    {
        _mother = unique_ptr<person>(&mother);
        _father = unique_ptr<person>(&father);
    }
private:
    string _name, _surname;
    unique_ptr<person> _mother, _father;
};
```

and then the main function:

```
int main()
{
    vector<unique_ptr<person> > people;
    vector<unique_ptr<person> >::iterator iter;

    people.push_back(unique_ptr<person>(new person("Marisa", "Miller")));
    people.push_back(unique_ptr<person>(new person("Andrew", "Clark")));
    people.push_back(unique_ptr<person>(new person("Thomas", "Clark")));
    people.push_back(unique_ptr<person>(new person("Elisa",  "Clark")));
    people.push_back(unique_ptr<person>(new person("Edward",  "Drake")));
    people.push_back(unique_ptr<person>(new person("Jhon",  "Drake")));

    // here is the problem:
    people.at(2).set_parents(???)

    for(iter = people.begin(); iter != people.end(); ++iter)
    {
        (*iter)->print();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Through the pointers, I would define the following family tree:

```
[Marisa Miller]     [Andrew Clark]
        |                   |
        +---------+---------+
                  |
                  +--------------[Thomas Clark]
                  |
                  +--------------[Elisa Clark]      [Edward Drake]
                                       |                   |
                                       +---------+---------+
                                                 |
                                           [Jhon Drake]
```

The question is:
how can I set the pointers (`_mother` and `_father`, through `get_parents(...)` function) to a previous element contained in the vector?
The `get_parents()` function may also be defined as:

```
void get_parents(person* mother, person* father)
```

or

```
void get_parents(unique_ptr<person> mother, unique_ptr<person> father)
```

Thanks for any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

An unique pointer is there so that the pointer is only at most on one place at all time. You are having more than 1 reference (in vector and possibly in the Person, if it is a father or mother).

You might want to look in using shared pointers and weak pointers:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr

Answer (score 0):

A `person` shouldn't own `_mother` and `_father`.

This is probably better:

```
// ...
private:
  std::string _name, _surname;
  person *_mother;
  person *_father;
};  // class person
```

Now if you keep `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<person>> people;` (i.e. the container owns its elements), you could write:

```
void person::set_parents(person &mother, person &father)
{
  _mother = &mother;
  _father = &father;
}

people[2]->set_parents(*people[0], *people[1]);
people[3]->set_parents(*people[0], *people[1]);
people[5]->set_parents(*people[3], *people[4]);
```

Also fix the `person::print` member function (it crashes in case of missing parents).